# VS code right click menu new class c#

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-code

I'm currently following some tutorial I bought which refers to 2 options called
"New C# class / New C# Interface", while I'm only seeing "New file."

I'm new to VSCODE and installed only C# from OmniSharp.

I'd like to have "New C# class" and "New C# Interface" in this menu as well.

[image]

Answer (score 39, accepted):

If you want those options in your right click menu, then you need to install the "C# Extensions" extension from the marketplace.

The link is [here](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=jchannon.csharpextensions)

Keep in mind this is just a shortcut extension, **it is not actually required**.

You can simply choose new file and give it the `.cs` extension if you want a new C# file.

Comment: That extension is no longer under development. Anyone know of a replacement? I know it isn't required but it still is quite convenient.

Comment: @DanielLidström There is an actively maintained fork for this extension, see my answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/73637303/6621862

Comment: It is showing deprecated. Is there any other options?

Answer (score 15):

It seems "C# Extensions" is no longer maintained. I tried it and it was not reliable. Sometimes it worked, sometimes it didn't.

But there is a similar extension called "VS Sharper for C#", see [here](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=eservice-online.vs-sharper).

Comment: Note that this project also appears dead and the repo contains no source code, so the several bugs and lack of newer language support cannot be taken over by the community.

Answer (score 4):

The "C# Extensions" extension from maccettura's answer is no longer maintained (per comment on that answer). However, there is a fork of that extension that is actively maintained at time of writing.

[Github repo for fork](https://github.com/KreativJos/csharpextensions)

[Extensions Marketplace](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=kreativ-software.csharpextensions)

Answer (score 4):

Since the good old "C# Extensions" by jchannon is deprecated, I found out that there is a new Official C# extension from Microsoft called [C# Dev Kit](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-dotnettools.csdevkit) and it works fine. It basically does everything needed to create a new C# class, etc.

Comment: For those who installed C# Dev Kit, but still can't find the way to add new classes: You need to go to Solution Explorer section after opening the project folder.

Answer (score 1):

Another extension with the same name (C# Extensions) was published by "JosKreativ" which can be an alternative.

[image]